# Как правильно расставить здесь запятые?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, спп, однородные-члены

Только после трагической смерти супруга она поняла, каким великим человеком он был и что если бы она уделяла ему больше своего внимания, любви, то, возможно, с ним бы не случилась беда.

Answer (score 3):

Никаких знаков не надо добавлять - всё на своих местах.

Основа главного предложения: она поняла.

Далее идут придаточные: каким (великим человеком он был) и что (с ним бы не случилась беда). Между придаточными не ставится запятая при наличии общего главного предложения.

Предложение *если бы она уделяла ему больше своего внимания, любви* - внутреннее придаточное; *то* отменяет запятую перед *если*.

Comment: Как-то странно. На мой взгляд запятая просится после "был" перед "и что если бы..."